# In Quorum, `eth.syncing` gives False even when blocks are imported

Tags: synchronization, geth, quorum

Due to overload, I lost my geth connection. When I start geth again, my old block's is gone. It again starts with 0th blocks. While doing the geth syncmode am getting false. Plz, help on these issues.

Geth/v1.8.18-stable-d715db38(quorum-v2.2.1)/linux-amd64/go1.9.2

How to fix the sync issues on Quorum??

Answer (score 1):

What consensus mechanism are you using and how large is the chain? There is a raft defect that was fixed in v2.2.2 where it fails to sync if the chain is out of sync by more than 8192 blocks (https://github.com/jpmorganchase/quorum/issues/614).